# Error Message: Operator '+' is not defined for string " and type 'Dictionary(Of String,Object)'

Tags: vb.net, json, serialization

Got this Error message while trying to deserialize JSON object

Error Message

Operator `+` is not defined for string "JPY: " and type `Dictionary(Of String,Object)`.

Here is the json object im trying to deserialize

> {"JPY": {"7d": "6510.92", "30d": "4434.76", "24h": "7027.46"}, "USD": {"7d": "65.09", "30d": "48.77", "24h": "74.26"}, "AUD": {"7d": "64.99", "30d": "49.10", "24h": "71.91"}, "CHF": {"7d": "66.86", "30d": "58.14", "24h": "69.57"}, "RUB": {"7d": "1896.79", "30d": "1472.11", "24h": "2206.51"}, "timestamp": 1364257203, "THB": {"30d": "1100.31"}, "CNY": {"7d": "417.58", "30d": "324.35", "24h": "466.92"}, "SLL": {"7d": "16719.16", "30d": "11865.62", "24h": "19185.45"}, "DKK": {"7d": "388.47", "30d": "350.27", "24h": "436.34"}, "BRL": {"7d": "166.21", "30d": "106.56", "24h": "182.34"}, "ILS": {"7d": "236.79", "30d": "218.19", "24h": "259.00"}, "GBP": {"7d": "44.16", "30d": "31.73", "24h": "49.22"}, "NZD": {"7d": "80.21", "30d": "59.29", "24h": "88.60"}, "PLN": {"7d": "218.66", "30d": "163.68", "24h": "249.94"}, "CAD": {"7d": "68.76", "30d": "50.16", "24h": "76.43"}, "SEK": {"7d": "445.63", "30d": "315.11", "24h": "510.58"}, "SGD": {"7d": "87.88", "30d": "61.97", "24h": "93.35"}, "HKD": {"7d": "550.10", "30d": "396.68", "24h": "571.82"}, "EUR": {"7d": "51.85", "30d": "38.65", "24h": "58.69"}}

Here's my code

```
Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim testObj = js.Deserialize(rt, New Object().GetType())

    out = "JPY: " + testObj("JPY") + Environment.NewLine
    out += "7days: " + testObj("7d") + Environment.NewLine
    out += "30days: " + testObj("30d") + Environment.NewLine
    out += "24hours: " + testObj("24h")
```

Comment: testObj("JPY") is an object, as can be clearly seen from the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do favor using the debugger, it can show you what the deserialized object looks like.  It is a dictionary of dictionaries, the equivalent VB.NET declaration would be Dictionary(Of String, Of Dictionary(Of String, String)).  Which makes this the proper code:

```
    Dim currency = testObj("JPY")
    out = "JPY: " + Environment.NewLine
    out += "7days: " + currency("7d") + Environment.NewLine
    out += "30days: " + currency("30d") + Environment.NewLine
    out += "24hours: " + currency("24h")
```